# For each not firing in the right order

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach, twitch

Good evening.

I'm currently working on an app that uses the twitch API.

For the first time I had to use the forEach JS command. But for some reason I cannot figure out, it seems kind of messy, as if for each wasn't firing in the right order, and as if the function is sometimes executed several time before the next array's element is fired.

I built a codepen that set the problem apart :

https://codepen.io/Hadrienallemon/pen/bLZJeX

As you can see in the pen, if you click several time on the test button, the result aren't always in the right order.

Here's the code :

HTML :

```
<button id="button">test button</button>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

CSS :

```
html,body{
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
}

.wrapper{
  height : 90%;
  width : 100%;
}

.awnser{
  background-color : tomato;
  margin : 50px auto;
  width : 60%;
  min-height : 10%;

}
```

JS :

```
var lives = ["nat_ali","krayn_live","streamerhouse","merry"];
$("button").on("click",function(){ 
  lives.forEach(function(element){
    $(".wrapper").empty();
      $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/"+ element +"?callback=?",function(quote){

        if (quote.stream != null){
          $(".wrapper").append("
          <div class = 'awnser'>
              <p>"+quote.stream.game+"</p>
          </div>");
        }
        else{
          $(".wrapper").append("
          <div class = 'awnser'>
            <span class = 'circle' style ='text-align : right'>
              <p style = 'display : inline-block;'>offline</p>
            </span>
          </div>");
       }

    })
      $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/"+ element +"?callback=?",function(quote){

        console.log(quote.logo);
        $(".awnser:last-child").append("
        <div style ='width : 10%; height : 10%;'>"+ quote.display_name +"
            <img src = '"+quote.logo+"' style = 'max-width : 100%;max-height : 100%;'></div>");

    }) 
  })  
})
```

Comment: For live versions, please use the **on-site** Stack Snippets, not off-site resources like jsFiddle. You create a Snippet with the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: The only thing that's appears to be happening in your `.forEach` is an ajax (`$.getJSON`) call, which, by definition, is **asynchronous** - so the requests will be initiating in order, but there's no way to determine the order they will be received.

Comment: Also your line `$(".wrapper").empty();` at the first line of the foreach tries to erase the container element every time. But in this case everything still appears because like @freedomn-m says, you're launching asynchronous processes with `$.getJSON`

Comment: Besides, you're hammering the server with 8 concurrent HTTP calls on each button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is **asynchronous**. Your `forEach` *starts* the calls in a given order, but they can *complete* in any order at all, completely chaotically.

If you want to process their completions in order, you can save each promise from `$.getJSON` in an array, wait for them to complete with `$.when` (they'll run in parallel, but your callback won't run until they're all done), and then process the results:

```
$.when.apply($, lives.map(element => $.getJSON(/*...*/))
.done((...results) => {
    // All calls are done, process results
    results.forEach(result => {
        // ...
    });
});
```

jQuery's `$.when` will call your `done` callback with an argument for each of the promises you pass it. In the above, we gather those up in an array via a rest parameter and then loop through it.

Or with pre-ES2015 syntax using the `arguments` pseudo-array:

```
$.when.apply($, lives.map(function(element) { return $.getJSON(/*...*/)})
.done(function() => {
    var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // All calls are done, process results
    results.forEach(function(result) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Your code:
/*var lives = ["nat_ali","krayn_live","streamerhouse","merry"];
$("button").on("click",function(){ 
  lives.forEach(function(element){
    $(".wrapper").empty();
      $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/"+ element +"?callback=?",function(quote){

        if (quote.stream != null){
          $(".wrapper").append("
          <div class = 'awnser'>
              <p>"+quote.stream.game+"</p>
          </div>");
        }
        else{
          $(".wrapper").append("
          <div class = 'awnser'>
            <span class = 'circle' style ='text-align : right'>
              <p style = 'display : inline-block;'>offline</p>
            </span>
          </div>");
       }

    })
      $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/"+ element +"?callback=?",function(quote){

        console.log(quote.logo);
        $(".awnser:last-child").append("
        <div style ='width : 10%; height : 10%;'>"+ quote.display_name +"
            <img src = '"+quote.logo+"' style = 'max-width : 100%;max-height : 100%;'></div>");

    }) 
  })  
})*/

// You need to use JQuery's method to get the data back in promises to know the order in which they are received and map the data together:
const lives = ["nat_ali","krayn_live","streamerhouse","merry"];
$(".wrapper").empty();
const streams = lives.map((val) => {
  return $.getJSON(`https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/${element}?callback=?`;
});
const users = lives.map((val) => {
  return $.getJSON(`https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/${element}?callback=?`;
});

$.when(streams).then(
  (streamsData) => {
    // Do what you need to for when the streamsData (array) is correlated to the array indices for the "lives" array defined above.
  },
  (err) => { /* handle API failures */ }
);
  
$.when(users).then(
  (usersData) => {
    // Do what you need to do for the usersData (array) that is correlated to the array indices for the "lives" array defined above.
  }
);
```